# How do I stop a Signer recipient using the ‘Assign to Someone Else’ action?

Tags: docusignapi

Although the ‘Assign to Someone Else' action should send a notification to the Sender when the Recipient has used this option, we need a way to prevent recipients from using this action in the first place. Is there an option we can set when we create the envelope?  Using REST.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `allowReassign` Envelope property to `false` in the **Create Envelope** request to prevent recipients from being able to *Assign to someone else*. It's a top-level property of the Envelope object, a peer of `emailSubject`, etc.

```
POST https://ENVIRONMENT/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER/envelopes
{
    "emailSubject": "Please Sign",
    "emailBlurb": "Please sign this contract. Thank you!",
    "allowReassign": "false",
    ...
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Reassigning Signing Responsibility at an account level by going to `Admin -> Signing Settings` and unchecking below options

- Allow recipients to change signing responsibility
- Allow senders to override change signing responsibility

If you uncheck both the settings then none of sender can set this setting neither from WEBApp nor from API. But you uncheck first setting and don't uncheck second then Sender can override the account level settings. So, if you want to disable this "Assign To Someone Else" feature then uncheck both checkboxes.

[image: Signing Responsibility]